# Selecionar os 10 maiores valores de uma variável de um dataframe no python?

Tags: python

Preciso descobrir os 10 maiores valores da variável **qtd_vendas** juntamente com a informação de **nome_cliente** de uma base de vendas.

Para saber quais os nomes dos 10 clientes que mais compraram.

Fazendo  `df['qtd_ordens'].max()` tenho o valor máximo de vendas, mas preciso dos 10 maiores juntamente com o nome desses clientes.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: O que vc já fez? Poste o código.

Comment: Tente também deixar mais claro as ferramentas que está uando. Não é apenas Python, é um Data Frame com Pandas. Sempre que possível, coloque exemplos de entrada e saída esperada para ajudar a entender exatamente o que se pretende fazer, o que tentou até agora e qual o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Pandas possui a função [`.nlargest()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html). Esta função recebe como parâmetros:

- `n` (`int`): Número de linhas a retornar
- `columns` (`list` or `str`): Coluna(s) utilizadas na ordenação
- `keep` (`‘first’`, `‘last’` ou `False`): Decide o que fazer com linhas duplicadas e o padrão é `‘first’`, ou seja, mantém a primeira.

Ela irá retornar um data frame com as `n` primeiras linhas do seu data frame `df` ordenado pela coluna `columns`. No seu caso, fica:

```
df.nlargest(10, 'qtd_ordens')
```

O mesmo resultado pode ser obtido combinando as funções [`.sort_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), que ordena o data frame, e [`.head()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html), que seleciona as primeiras linhas:

```
df.sort_values(by='qtd_vendas', ascending=False).head(10)
```

Ai, para seleconar apenas as colunas `'nome_cliente'` e `'qtd_vendas'`, fica:

```
df.nlargest(10, 'qtd_ordens')[['nome_cliente','qtd_ordens']]
```

Comment: era isso que eu precisava! obrigado Alex